# PHP string parsing for array manipulation

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    1 => array(
        'quote' => 'To be or not to be',
        'citation' => 'Hamlet'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'quote' => 'The left hand knows that the right hand is doing',
        'citation' => 'President Bush'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'quote' => 'Another quote',
        'citation' => 'Another person'
    )
);
```

I have a function that generates a select box with the number index as the value and the "quote" index as the label.

However, I would like to change my code to add more general support. I would like to pass in a parameter such as "{quote} – {citation}" to my select box generator function and it will replace strings between the curly braces with the index value defined above.

I am in need of the PHP function that will allow this. I know I've used it once before, but it was very long ago...

Comment: sprintf() ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function format_array($pattern, array $array) {
    return array_map(
        function (array $data) use ($pattern) {
            return preg_replace_callback(
                '/\{(\w+)\}/',
                function (array $match) use ($data) { return $data[$match[1]]; },
                $pattern
            );
         },
         $array
    );
}

$array = format_array('{quote} – {citation}', $array);
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/laHR4

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using vsprintf:

```
$format = '%s &dash; %s';

foreach ($array as $val => $label) {
    if (is_array($label)) {
        $label = isset($format) ? vsprintf($format, $label) : current($label);
    }
    $output .= '<option value="' . $val . '"' . (isset($options['value']) && $options['value'] == $val ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $label . '</option>';
}
```